# Impossible to make packages available through setuptools or pip

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools

I searched for hundreds of similar questions and none of them worked for me, I'm sure I am missing something very obvious but I still can't figure what. Here is my problem:

I have a python project with multiple packages, I need some of them to be available from anywhere in the server so if I update a function I can use the same version everywhere that is importing it. Here is my structure:

```
myproject
   |
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- setup.py
   |
   |------api
   |       |
   |       |---__init__.py
   |       |---main.py      
   |       |
   |       endpoints
   |          |
   |          |-- __init__.py
   |          |-- something1.py
   |          |-- something2.py
   |          
   |
   |------database
   |         |
   |         |-- __init__.py
   |         |-- important1.py
   |
   |
   |------tools
   |         |-- __init__.py
   |         |-- important2.py
   |         |-- something3.py
```

I need to import `important1.py` and `important2.py` from `something1.py`, `something2.py` and `something3.py`

I tried to run `python setup.py install` and it doesn't throw any errors, here is its contents:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='myproject', version='1.0', packages=find_packages())
```

I printed find_packages() and it is returning the right packages, I also tried running `pip install -e .`

Here is the output of `pip list`

```
Package            Version   Location
------------------ --------- --------------------
Jinja2             2.11.2
MarkupSafe         1.1.1
myproject          1.0       /root/myproject
```

Yet when I try to run `import myproject` I get  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'`

I also tried to manually add `/root/myproject` to `sys.path`, and to add it through a `.pth` file, and everything I tried, I tried using a virtualenv and without a virtualenv, it seems impossible to me that this should be that hard, I must be missing something

Comment: Are you running your python code as root? You placed your package in a place only the root user can read

Comment: Yes I am, I don't think it is a permission issue

Comment: You have a project named `myproject` but you don't have a package `myproject` inside it so you cannot import it. Please read the docs on packaging: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/